# What is the parasitic resistance due to an IC package in a mosfet? (or any package)

Tags: power, mosfet, resistance, rdson

How much resistance does the package of an IC contribute to the paraistic resitance of a circuit? (most applicable to mosfets)

Comment: Does it even matter? I mean, wouldn't the output impedance of the circuit itself be significantly larger than the bond wire/pin resistance?

Comment: If your designing power circuits, mΩ's can matter nowadays, with many new power mosfets having rdsons in the mΩ range. If your selecting components, you know if you get a the same die in a D2 instead of a MLP package you'll get lower resistance.

Comment: That is not something that the manufacturer take into account when they specify rds in the datasheet?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure on that one, probably. Either way, if your buying the same part number the package makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

It's below 2.5mΩ at DC on most packages

[image]

[Understanding the Effect of Power MOSFET Package Parasitics on
VRM Circuit Efficiency at Frequencies above 1MHz](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/whitepaper/pcimeur03packageparasitics.pdf)